# Long Press on Notifications on iPhone XR Not Working

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

I have a new iPhone XR running iOS 12.1.

When I get a new notification (such as an iMessage, a Reminder, etc.) on the lock screen, I should be able to long-press on the notification (instead of force/3D touch) and see shortcut options (or quick reply, in the case of iMessage).

These options are all enabled in Settings and I have tried rebooting my device and it still doesn't work. FaceID has unlocked the device and I know additional options are available because I can still swipe notifications to the right and select "View" which shows what I would expect to see when long-pressing the notification.

I submitted a radar to Apple, so hopefully they address it. But I just wanted to see if anyone else has run into this and found a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure that's how it's supposed to work on the iPhone XR, at least not yet. Perhaps you can [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/341814/edit) your question to include a screenshot of the options you have enabled in Settings?

Comment: As you've stated, 3D Touch is not available on the iPhone XR.  Long-press gestures replace those actions.  I've seen multiple complaints all over the web, including Apple Support forums, about long-press not working correctly so you're not alone.  Filing the radar is one option.  Erasing your device and setting it up as 'new', instead of from a backup, is another option as is returning your device for a replacement.  You're still in your replacement window so it should only cost you time.

Comment: It isn't that it is malfunctioning, Apple has not added support for long press on lock screen notifications. They have on the iPad, so there is future hope.

Comment: @StephenCollins If you want to post that as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't that it is malfunctioning, Apple has not added support for long press on lock screen notifications. They have on the iPad, so there is future hope.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this feature is coming to **iOS 12.1.1**: https://9to5mac.com/2018/11/08/iphone-xr-expand-notifications-haptic-touch/

I'm going to install the beta and try it out. :) Sweet!

Comment: I can confirm that it works on iOS 12.1.1.